# Is My T-SQL Query Written Efficiently?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
SELECT o.oxxxxID, 
       m.mxxxx, 
       txxxx, 
       exxxxName, 
       paxxxxe, 
       fxxxxe,
       pxxxx, 
       axxxx, 
       nxxxx, 
       nxxxx, 
       nxxxx, 
       ixxxx, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, o.dateCreated, 103)
FROM Offer o INNER JOIN Mxxxx m ON o.mxxxxID = m.mxxxxID
             INNER JOIN EXXXX e ON e.exxxxID = o.exxxxID 
             INNER JOIN PXXXX p ON p.pxxxxxxID = o.pxxxxID
             INNER JOIN Fxxxx f ON f.fxxxxxID = o.fxxxxxID
WHERE o.cxxxxID = 11
```

The above query is expected to be executed via website by approximately 1000 visitors daily. **Is it badly written and has a high chance to cause lack of performance? If yes, can you please suggest me how to improve it.**

**NOTE: every table has only one index (Primary key).**

Comment: All the replacements you've done make this very hard to read. Beyond that, it's probably not practical to give a useful answer to this question without knowing what the structure of the tables and their indexes are.

Comment: Query plan estimate says what? (I am really holding off a down-vote: make sure to get familiar with the basic tools provided so that these kinds of questions can be answered internally. If there *is* a performance issue and the plans *are* good, then other techniques may be employed. However, this would be asked in another form of question.)

Comment: I would **definitely** also put indices on the foreign key columns of all tables; it helps with JOIN performance

Comment: -1 for completely gratuitous replacements and insufficient information for anyone to answer sensibly. What are the table schemas? For all we know `e.exxxxID` and `o.exxxxID ` might have completely different datatypes that require implicit conversion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing the content of the data, but it looks like a perfectly valid SQL statement.  The many joins will likely degrade performance a bit, but you can use a fw strategies for improving performance...  I have a few ideas.

- indexed views can often improve performance
- stored procedures  will optomize the query for you and save the optomized query
- or if possible, create a one-off table that's not live, but contains the data from this statement, only in a non-normalized format.  This on-off table would need tp be updated regularly, but you can get some huge performance boosts using this strategy if it's possible in your situation.

For general performance issues and ideas, this is a good place to start, if you haven't alredy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647793.aspx

This one is very good as well: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.01.boostperformance.aspx

Comment: My notes: The only time (on my smallish data-sets ~ 200k) when many inner joins have bit me is when not using proper covering indexes. Also the placement of the indexes vs. the tables makes a big difference (e.g. a small table scan at the end is quite cheap). Cross joins on the other hand... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Looks good to me.

Now for the performance piece you need to make sure you have the proper indexes covering the columns you are filtering and joining (Foreign Keys, etc).

A good start would be to do an Actual Execution Plan or, the easy route, run it against the Indexing Tunning Wizard.

The actual execution plan in SQL 2008 (perhaps 2005 as well) will give you missing indexes hints already on the top.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend mostly on the keys and indexes defined on the tables.  If you could provide those a better answer could be given.  While the query looks ok (other than the xxx's in all the names), if you're joining on fields with no indexes, or there field in the where clause has no index then you may run into performance issues on larger data sets.

Answer (score 2):

It looks pretty good to me. Probably the only improvement I might make is to output `o.datecreated` as is and let the client format it.

You could also add indexes to the join columns.

There may also be a potential to create an indexed view if performance is an issue and space isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your query looks perfectly good written. The only point that we can't know if it can be improved is the existence of indexes and keys on the columns that you are using on the JOINS and the WHERE statement. Other than that, I don't see anything that can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have single indexes on the primary keys, then it is unlikely the indexes will be covering for all the data output in your select statement.  So what will happen is that the query can efficiently locate the rows for each primary key but it will need to use bookmark lookups to find the data rows and extract the additional columns.

So, although the query itself is probably fine (except for the date conversion) as long as all these columns are truly needed in the output, the execution plan could probably be improved by adding additional columns to your indexes.  A clustered index key is not allowed to have included columns, and this is probably also your primary key enforcement, and you are unlikely to want to add other columns to your primary key, so this would mean creating an additional non-clustered index with the PK column first and then including additional columns.

At this point the indexes will cover the query and it will not need to do the bookmark lookups.  Note that the indexes need to support the most common usage scenarios and that the more indexes you add, the slower your write performance will be, since all the indexes will need to be updated.

In addition, you might also want to review your constraints, since these can be used by the optimizer to eliminate joins if a table is not used for any output columns when the optimizer can determine there will not be an outer join or cross join which would eliminate or multiply rows.